# How to show alert just one time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I'm working with iBeacons and want to show alert when the user is near the iBeacon. For this I do:

```
for closest in beacons as! [CLBeacon] {
        if closest.major == 4660 && closest.minor == 4648 {
            var customIcon:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "location2.png")
            var customColor:UIColor! = UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 236/255.0, alpha: 1)

            var alert = JSSAlertView().show(
                self,
                title: "You're near the beacon!",
                buttonText: "Dismiss",
                color: customColor,
                iconImage: customIcon
            )
            alert.setTextTheme(.Light)
        }
    }
```

It works, but a problem is that it shows many times, one by one and user cannot Dismiss this alert. It's because of that my app update the location of ibeacon every second for find new ibeacons.

Can I show this alert just one time?

I do the next:

```
        var flag = 0
        if flag == 0 {
            var alert = JSSAlertView().show(
                self,
                title: "You're near the beacon!",
                buttonText: "Dismiss",
                color: customColor,
                iconImage: customIcon
            )
            alert.setTextTheme(.Light)
        }
```

but it doesn't work, too

Comment: `var alert = JSSAlertView()` if this was a class level property you could check if it was showing and if it was not, show it. or have a `Bool` on the object and set it once, the first time and not again.

Comment: check if the answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It seemed i had overlooked the fact that `locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)` is called whenever the ranges change. So if you want an alert to happen once you would add a property to your class

`var isShowing:Bool = false`

then adjust the code to factor in the boolean

```
for closest in beacons as! [CLBeacon] { 
    if (closest.major == 4660 && closest.minor == 4648) && isShowing == false {    
        var customIcon:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "location2.png") 
        var customColor:UIColor! = UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 236/255.0, alpha: 1) 

        var alert = JSSAlertView().show( 
                        self, 
                        title: "You're near the beacon!", 
                        buttonText: "Dismiss", 
                        color: customColor, 
                        iconImage: customIcon 
                    ) 
        alert.setTextTheme(.Light) 
        isShowing = true 
        break
    } 
}
```

Comment: hmm put a breakpoint in the if statement's and see if `shouldShow` is being set properly @OrkhanAlizade

Comment: `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {`

Comment: `locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)` gets called whenever the signal strength changes. so thats why you are getting more then one popup @OrkhanAlizade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80731/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-cream-corn).

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit to @cream-corn's code

```
 var shouldShow = true
    for closest in beacons as! [CLBeacon] {
        if closest.major == 4660 && closest.minor == 4648 {

           break
        }
    }
    if (shouldShow == true) {
        var customIcon:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "location2.png")
        var customColor:UIColor! = UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 236/255.0, alpha: 1)

        var alert = JSSAlertView().show(
                self,
                title: "You're near the beacon!",
                buttonText: "Dismiss",
                color: customColor,
                iconImage: customIcon
            )
        alert.setTextTheme(.Light)
        shouldShow = false
    }
```

Comment: the same result. By updating the range of beacons it shows me alert

Comment: this code will show the alert, whether or not any beacons are in range. the problem is the method `locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)` gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the `flag` thing. But if you put `var flag = 0` inside that method then flag will always be 0. 
You have to declare `flag` in the class, not the function like this:

```
class myClass {
var flag = 0
    func myFunction() {
        /*more code here...*/
        if flag == 0 {
            var alert = JSSAlertView().show(
                self,
                title: "You're near the beacon!",
                buttonText: "Dismiss",
                color: customColor,
                iconImage: customIcon
            )
            alert.setTextTheme(.Light)
        }
    }
}
```